# YouTube Data API returns more results than maxResults

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have created this PHP script that print outs the specified number of latest youtube videos from a youtube channel. I'm setting the maxResults to 10 but it returns hundreds of results. Please go through the code and help.

```
<?php

$API_Url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/';
$API_Key = '...';
$channelId = 'UCX6OQ3DkcsbYNE6H8uQQuVA';

$parameter = [
    'id'=> $channelId,
    'part'=> 'contentDetails',
    'key'=> $API_Key
];
$channel_URL = $API_Url . 'channels?' . http_build_query($parameter);
$json_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($channel_URL), true);

$playlist=$json_details['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

$parameter = [
    'part'=> 'snippet',
    'playlistId' => $playlist,
    'maxResults'=> 10,
    'key'=> $API_Key
];
$channel_URL = $API_Url . 'playlistItems?' . http_build_query($parameter);
$json_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($channel_URL), true);


$my_videos = [];
foreach($json_details['items'] as $video){
    //$my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
    $my_videos[] = array( 'v_id'=>$video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], 'v_name'=>$video['snippet']['title'] );
}

while(isset($json_details['nextPageToken'])){
    $nxt_page_URL = $channel_URL . '&pageToken=' . $json_details['nextPageToken'];
    $json_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($nxt_page_URL), true);
    foreach($json_details['items'] as $video)
        $my_videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
}

print_r($my_videos);

//foreach($my_videos as $video){
    //if(isset($video)){

        //echo '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='. $video['v_id'] .'">
                    //<div>'. $video['v_name'] .'</div>
            //</a><br><br><br>';
    //}
//}
```

And the extra results it is returning don't even have a title or id. See the image for yourself

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You have loop that appears to keep getting more results, so isn't it expected you'd have more than 10? Did you write this code?

Comment: not all of it...i followed a youtube tutorial

Comment: Okay, does that answer your question then? The block starting `while(isset($json_details['nextPageToken'])){` gets the next page, and then the page after that and continues until the API doesn't return a `nextPageToken` parameter in the response each time adding the video ids to `$my_videos`.

Comment: and according to me, the loop is irrelevant. the api is already sending all those results.

Comment: ok. so what changes are you suggesting

Comment: If you only want those first 10, get rid of or comment out the entire while loop block.

Comment: thank you very much. you can answer it if you want me to upvote and accept your answer so that you can get xp.

Comment: @VishuRana I suggest resetting your api-key since you posted it to the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get so many items is that after the first request, you have a `while` loop that makes subsequent requests to the YouTube API for the next page of data until `nextPageToken` is not found in the response payload, meaning you can be making anything from 1 to tens or hundreds of requests depending on how many pages of data are available each bringing back up to 10 additional items.

Each individual request will be bringing back 10 items at a time as you specified, but the cumulative total is obviously a lot more than that. Since you're only interested in the first 10, simply removing the `while` block should stop the code from making any more requests after the first one and thus won't add them to the array.